# How should I merge two dataframes so that the resulting dataframe does not have NaN values for an entire column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes called "co_df" (has 2 columns -> Date, Average) and "traffic_df" (has 6 columns that include 'Date' as well). The co_df dataframe has the CO emissions data from every day in 2019, meaning it has 365 columns. The traffic_df dataframe has 587 columns. I only want to work with the 2019 values.
The dataframes are as shown -

[image: co_df]

[image: traffic_df]

I want to join the two dataframes **by date** so that the resultant dataframe would have 7 columns. So, I wanted to try left merge and this is the code I wrote ->

```
df = pd.merge(co_df, traffic_df, how="left", on="Date")
```

However, this results in a dataframe with 365 rows but the Average column only has value and all the other columns from traffic_df are all NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**dummy sets**

```
co_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03','2019-01-04'],
                    'Average': [1, 2, 3, 4]
                    })

traffic_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-13','2019-01-14'],
                           'Highway': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'Section': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'Section Length': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'ADT': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'AADT': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           })
```

**code**

```
df = pd.merge(co_df, traffic_df, on="Date", how="outer")
```

**result**

```
df
Out[10]: 
         Date  Average  Highway  Section  Section Length  ADT  AADT
0  2019-01-01      1.0      1.0      1.0             1.0  1.0   1.0
1  2019-01-02      2.0      NaN      NaN             NaN  NaN   NaN
2  2019-01-03      3.0      NaN      NaN             NaN  NaN   NaN
3  2019-01-04      4.0      NaN      NaN             NaN  NaN   NaN
4  2019-01-12      NaN      2.0      2.0             2.0  2.0   2.0
5  2019-01-13      NaN      3.0      3.0             3.0  3.0   3.0
6  2019-01-14      NaN      4.0      4.0             4.0  4.0   4.0
```